# Detecting if route is part of a resource

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-routing

Is there a standard Laravel way to check if a named route is part of a resource?

For instance, in a Blade template I can do:

```
@if(strpos(Route::currentRouteName(), 'posts') === 0)
     Yep, you're viewing a post.index, post.edit, post.preview, etc.
@else
     Nothing to do with a post.
@if
```

Wondering if I've glossed over some standard way of doing it or if this is *it*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And I just figured it out:

```
Route::is('posts.*')
```